# How to hide completed event from view result based on it's end date?

Tags: datetime, views

I have created an Event Type pages which have date field Start Date-End Date, how do I hide completed event in view result or else is there any other way to unpublished them automatically?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?  Are you using views?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7

Comment: How are you displaying the content?  Node view? Views?  If you are using views I can explain how to do this. It would be done by filter criteria against the End-date field

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screenshot]

You should Enable the "Date Views" module first. Then you will be able to find the Date CCK fields available in the filter criteria as Expected. You will also be able to provide a relative date in the filter criteria. Refer Screenshot.

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) module, which will publish/unpublish nodes after specified date(s).

Comment: I tried with Scheduler Module but I do not want specify unpublished date manually, it should be take from date field (end date value)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you're using Views or if you haven't understood that tag, but if you actually are, you can set the filter criteria like that:

[image]

Good luck!